# In VueJS, how can I generate dynamic background images based on the Route?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Is there a way in VueJS to create dynamic backgrounds based on the Route? For instance, I have the followings routes:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: "/:col",
    name: "collections",
    component: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "collections" */ "../views/CollectionsView.vue"
      ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "staked",
        name: "staked",
        component: () =>
          import(/* webpackChunkName: "staked" */ "../views/StakedView.vue"),
      },
      {
        path: "unstaked",
        name: "unstaked",
        component: () =>
          import(
            /* webpackChunkName: "unstaked" */ "../views/UnstakedView.vue"
          ),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I would like to set a different background image for each of the dynamic routes under the named route "collections", so "/collection1/..." would display a different background image than "/collection2/.

Here is my template inside AppView.vue:

```html
<template>
  <div class="background">
    <div
      :style="{
        backgroundImage: image,
      }"
    >
      <TheAppHeader />
      <div class="main m-auto">
        <TheTitle />
        <router-view />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I don't know how I can grab that collection name from the route and use it to get the desired background image into "".

My background images are all in the /src/assets/ directory.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `watch` property for this

```
watch: {
  '$route.params'(currentParam) {
    if (currentParam == '/collection1') {
      this.image = <put your image here>
    }
    else if (currentParam == '/collection2') {
      this.image = <put your another image here>
    }
  }
}
```

Please use to colsole current param to check your required/target values

Answer (score 0):

Can use `$route.params` like this.

```js
watch: {
  '$route.params'(currentParam) {
      this.image = `assets/images/${currentParam}.jpg`
    // i.e. assets/images/collection1.jpg

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This looks like a good solution. Unfortunately, when I use this code I am getting a parse error in VS Code:
any
Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (14:31)eslint
No quick fixes available

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the path to your background image as a prop to a route.

```
// In routes.js
const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
    props: {
        backgroundImage: './src/assets/route-backgrounds/home.jpg',
    },
  }]

// In component
  props: [ "backgroundImage" ],

// In template
<div :style="{ backgroundImage: `url('${backgroundImage}')` }"></div>
```